# Добавить в unnest() with ordinality

Tags: sql, postgresql

В данном запросе:

```
SELECT dw.name_of_day, count( * ) AS num_flights
FROM (
SELECT unnest( days_of_week ) AS num_of_day
FROM routes
WHERE departure_city = 'Москва'
) AS r,
unnest( '{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }'::integer[],
'{ "Пн.", "Вт.", "Ср.", "Чт.", "Пт.", "Ср.", "Вс."}'::text[]
) AS dw( num_of_day, name_of_day )
WHERE r.num_of_day = dw.num_of_day
GROUP BY r.num_of_day, dw.name_of_day
ORDER BY r.num_of_day;
```

Нужно заменить массив чисел `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }` на `WITH ORDINALITY`. Уже что только не перепробовал, ругается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unnest( '{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }'::integer[],
'{ "Пн.", "Вт.", "Ср.", "Чт.", "Пт.", "Ср.", "Вс."}'::text[]
) AS dw( num_of_day, name_of_day )
```

заменить на

```
unnest('{ "Пн.", "Вт.", "Ср.", "Чт.", "Пт.", "Ср.", "Вс."}'::text[]) 
  with ordinality 
  as dw( name_of_day , num_of_day)
```

Comment: Благодарю, выручили!